# C# List<string> OrderBy Split

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to just Order a list by the value after a split.

For example my data looks like this.

```
Z|2  
A|1
```

I want my list to be order by the value after the split

so I would get

```
A|1  
Z|2
```

This is what i'm using but I get the error:

> *{"Input string was not in a correct format."}*

`All = All.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split('|')[1])).ToList();`

Any help would be awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: Are there no exceptions to the rule? For example, are there any inputs that might look like `B| ` or `C|X` or [anything non-numeric in the second spot]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work:

```
All = All.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split('|').Last())).ToList();
```

What would work even better though would be to have a list of a structured type instead of a list of dumb strings. For example, you could have a list of `Tuple<string, int>` and simply sort it by the second member. You could also put the tuple into an ordered container and have sorting done automatically.

Comment: @KirkWoll: That's true; edited to fix the answer. But to be frank, I 'm intending to focus on the "even better" part.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: I do find it much more readable than `[1]` -- it's not the same of course in the general case, but still.

Comment: Last is useful if it is truly the last element. His example `A|1` could in reality be `A|1|a|bunch of text|not relevant|to question`.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram or maybe `a|bunch of text|not relevant|to question|A|1`

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: In that case I think we can agree what needs improvement is not the answer but the question.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov, in that case, it *would* be relevant, as he is specifically looking in the *second* spot. ;)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram well ok, he is having a problem and all he presented to use is a context, where `Last()` is a very good solution.

Comment: @Jon I tried this getting the same error, the data is valid all of these fields contains two columns with a '|' splitting them and this still gives me the error

Comment: @Mike: Well, either these simple .NET methods have a bug or the data is not exactly what you show. Where would you put your money? There are some items that do not fit your description (perhaps there is additional whitespace?), find them.

Comment: I agree with Jon. @Mike, use Ctrl+Alt+E to break on exceptions. When it breaks, check the input that should still be visible in the debugger. See what it looks like, then you should know how to address it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip invalid format first, assume put in the top:

```
All = All.OrderBy(s => {
    var parts = s.Split('|');

    if (parts.Length != 2)
        return int.MinValue;

    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(parts[1], out value))
        return value;

    return int.MinValue;
});
```

Comment: Do you think your approach would work for `A|B1`? If trying to handle the special case of a non-numeric second input, it should probably be more robust than this.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: more constraint

Comment: OK, how about `Xbox|360`. I could be wrong, but I don't think his inputs are all expected to be *one letter-bar-one number*, but rather *text-bar-number*.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Edit my answer again

Comment: OK. Looking better. *Close* to Guffa's, but you have a bit more code to handle lines that do not even split. Your last line of text is now obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TryParse` if you have values that you are not sure about. This would put any values that are not possible to parse last in the list:

```
All = All.OrderBy(s => {
  int value;
  if (!Int32.TryParse(s.Split('|')[1], out value)) {
    value = Int32.MaxValue;
  }
  return value;
}).ToList();
```

(Note: The largest possible int value is used to place those items last in the list, if you would have any other items with the value 2147483648, they would be mixed with those. For a solution that works with that values too, you would need to create a comparer instead of a delegate that merely extracts the value from the string.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine - you must have some invalid data. Double-check the values in your initial list to make sure you don't have any non-numeric values after the pipe, or anything else like that.

**EDIT**

You could always catch errors and handle them differently, like:

```
// This would put all failures at the top of the list
All = All.OrderBy(s => {
    try { return int.Parse(s.Split('|')[1]); }
    catch { return 0; }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Joe - know all the data contains at least one |

Comment: It's not just the pipe - the error seems to be that there is invalid data after the pipe, like `X|X`, which would make `int.Parse` fail. Your split seems to be ok - if a pipe was missing, you'd get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` I believe.

Comment: If I'm going to take this route, I would like look at an answer like Guffa's that uses non-exceptional code. Barring that, if I'm expecting invalid inputs, I am going to catch the exception that matches that expectation, not *all of them*. But truthfully, I think step one for the OP is to verify his inputs. Obviously, something is not matching his expectation. Perhaps the ordering *should* fail.