# C# List Numeric Sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting

I've tried a lot of methods, but I've always had problems with string expressions that are space characters. Then I came across [this](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/c-numeric-sorting-revisited/) blog post and thought it might be useful but I do not know how to use it unfortunately. I have a list,

**Edit:** Game instead of Crysis, Star Citizen, 34 Games, Call of Duty. I use the game name to give an example

Game 3.1 1

Game 3.2 10

Game 3.3 11

Game 3.2 9

Game 3.18 7

Game 3.27 12

Game 3.11.2 13

Game 3.2 2

Game 3.8 5

Game 3.10 7

For Example;

```
        List<GameVersion> GameVersionList = new List<GameVersion>();
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.1", Code = "1" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.2", Code = "10" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.3", Code = "11" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.2", Code = "9" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.18", Code = "7" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.27", Code = "12" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.11.2", Code = "13" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.2", Code = "2" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.8", Code = "5" });
        GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.10", Code = "7" });

        public class GameVersion
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
        }
```

It should be like that;

Game 3.1 1

Game 3.2 10

Game 3.2 9

Game 3.2 2

Game 3.3 11

Game 3.8 5

Game 3.10 7

Game 3.11.2 13

Game 3.18 7

Game 3.27 12

I want to be sorted by name. So, how to use this CompareNumeric?

```
        public static int CompareNumeric(this string s, string other)
    {
        if (s != null && other != null &&
            (s = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty)).Length > 0 &&
            (other = other.Replace(" ", string.Empty)).Length > 0)
        {
            int sIndex = 0, otherIndex = 0;

            while (sIndex < s.Length)
            {
                if (otherIndex >= other.Length)
                    return 1;

                if (char.IsDigit(s[sIndex]))
                {
                    if (!char.IsDigit(other[otherIndex]))
                        return -1;

                    // Compare the numbers
                    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(), otherBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while (sIndex < s.Length && char.IsDigit(s[sIndex]))
                    {
                        sBuilder.Append(s[sIndex++]);
                    }

                    while (otherIndex < other.Length && char.IsDigit(other[otherIndex]))
                    {
                        otherBuilder.Append(other[otherIndex++]);
                    }

                    long sValue = 0L, otherValue = 0L;

                    try
                    {
                        sValue = Convert.ToInt64(sBuilder.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (OverflowException) { sValue = Int64.MaxValue; }

                    try
                    {
                        otherValue = Convert.ToInt64(otherBuilder.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (OverflowException) { otherValue = Int64.MaxValue; }

                    if (sValue < otherValue)
                        return -1;
                    else if (sValue > otherValue)
                        return 1;
                }
                else if (char.IsDigit(other[otherIndex]))
                    return 1;
                else
                {
                    int difference = string.Compare(s[sIndex].ToString(), other[otherIndex].ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

                    if (difference > 0)
                        return 1;
                    else if (difference < 0)
                        return -1;

                    sIndex++;
                    otherIndex++;
                }
            }

            if (otherIndex < other.Length)
                return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you change the model to not let the version be part of the name but its own property?

Comment: If you just want to order by a name field, Why don't just use `GameVersionList.OrderBy(o=> o.Name).ToList()`

Comment: The name actually contains the file name, and the space character. I want it to be sorted like Windows Explorer.

Comment: You can use the Windows API to do a "natural sort": See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538443/106159

Comment: @YıldırayEyüpErdoğan It shouldn't be a problem. If all the items on the list starts with the same string `Game `, the list will be order by the number treated as a string. `"3.2.1"` will always be sorted before `"3.2.5"` or `"3.3"`

Comment: As a note, if all the items on the list doesn't start with the same string, you can split them by space and just use the last part of the string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684959/c-sharp-liststring-orderby-split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [the Windows API `StrCmpLogicalW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx) to compare strings using a "natural" sort order.

You can encapsulate this in a `List<T>` extension:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class ListExt
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string lhs, string rhs);

    public static void SortNatural<T>(this List<T> self, Func<T, string> stringSelector)
    {
        self.Sort((lhs, rhs) => StrCmpLogicalW(stringSelector(lhs), stringSelector(rhs)));
    }

    public static void SortNatural(this List<string> self)
    {
        self.Sort(StrCmpLogicalW);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it for your example like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<GameVersion> GameVersionList = new List<GameVersion>();
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.1", Code = "1" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.2", Code = "10" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.3", Code = "11" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.2", Code = "9" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.18", Code = "7" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.27", Code = "12" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.11.2", Code = "13" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.2", Code = "2" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.8", Code = "5" });
    GameVersionList.Add(new GameVersion() { Name = "Game 3.10", Code = "7" });

    GameVersionList.SortNatural(item => item.Name);

    foreach (var item in GameVersionList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ": " + item.Code);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Game 3.1: 1
Game 3.2: 10
Game 3.2: 9
Game 3.2: 2
Game 3.3: 11
Game 3.8: 5
Game 3.10: 7
Game 3.11.2: 13
Game 3.18: 7
Game 3.27: 12
```

which matches your requirement.

Comment: What if every name is not the same?

Comment: @YıldırayEyüpErdoğan Well then it will be sorted by name first, then by version number. You don't have an example of your expected output for this input; perhaps you should specify it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to add so much complexity. Using LINQ, split the Name field on Space and take last element (number). You can then use `Version` class to perform sorting:

```
var Sorted = GameVersionList.OrderBy(g => new Version(g.Name.Split(' ').Last());
```

If you want to sort on the name part first and then by version, change the above slightly:

```
var Sorted = GameVersionList.OrderBy(g => g.Name).ThenBy(g => new Version(g.Name.Split(' ').Last());
```

Notice how the primary sort will not (effectively) be affected by the version number

Comment: Did not know there was a version class that implements `IComparable`. Very nice.

Comment: What if every name is not the same?

Comment: That doesn't make much difference. All that will change is the way to isolate Number part from the string. If u provide some examples, I can probably update my one-liner.

Comment: Game instead of Crysis, Star Citizen, 34 Games, Call of Duty etc. etc.

Comment: The above code should still work since we're using `.Last()`, so even if the name part contains multiple word, last will always give us the number part. The above will only fail if the number is NOT the last entity in the field.

Answer (score 1):

If every name is not the same as you commented, you can just take the substring after that space, convert it to double and sort it like

```
GameVersionList.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(
x.Name.Substring(
x.Name.IndexOf(' '))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try OrderBy Name

`var sortedList = GameVersionList.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();`

Comment: I do not really want to use this, can you examine CompareNumeric above? Because this way sorting like; 3.1 1, 3.10 7, 3.11.2 13.  should be Game 3.1 1

Game 3.2 10

Game 3.2 9

Game 3.2 2

Game 3.3 11

Game 3.8 5

Game 3.10 7

Game 3.11.2 13

Game 3.18 7

Game 3.27 12

Answer (score 0):

If you have game names that can consist of more than one word and possibly no version number at all, then you need to implement something a bit more complex.

We will use a class that implements `IComparer<string>` interface for comparing game names.

The `public int Compare(string x, string y)` method will:

- use `Regex` to split up game name into Name and Version parts
- compare names - if names are not equal, sort by name (eg *Alpha* vs *Bravo*)
- split up versions into an array using `.` as delimeter (eg *1.33.2* => *{1, 33, 2}*)
- compare each (sub-)version - if a pair is not equal, sort here (eg *1.33* vs *1.32*)
- if one version has a deeper sub-version level than the second, then sort using this (eg *3.2* vs *3.2.1*)

```cs
class GameNameComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    static readonly Regex regx = new Regex(@"^(?<Name>.*) (?<Version>[\d\.]+)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

    private static GameNameComparer instance;
    public static GameNameComparer Comparer
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new GameNameComparer();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private GameNameComparer() { }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var m1 = regx.Match(x);
        var m2 = regx.Match(y);

        if (m1.Success && m2.Success)
        {
            var name1 = m1.Groups["Name"].Value;
            var ver1 = m1.Groups["Version"].Value;
            var name2 = m2.Groups["Name"].Value;
            var ver2 = m2.Groups["Version"].Value;

            if (String.Equals(name1, name2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var ver1Levels = ver1.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                var ver2Levels = ver2.Split(new char[] { '.' });

                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(ver1Levels.Length, ver2Levels.Length); i++)
                {
                    int ver1LevelNo = 0;
                    int ver2LevelNo = 0;
                    int compare = 0;

                    if (Int32.TryParse(ver1Levels[i], out ver1LevelNo) && Int32.TryParse(ver2Levels[i], out ver2LevelNo))
                    {
                        compare = ver1LevelNo.CompareTo(ver2LevelNo);
                        if (compare != 0)
                            return compare;
                    }

                    compare = ver1Levels[i].CompareTo(ver2Levels[i]);
                    if (compare != 0)
                        return compare;
                }

                return ver1Levels.Length.CompareTo(ver2Levels.Length);
            }

            return String.Compare(name1, name2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        return String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

We can now use this class to sort the game list correctly:

```cs
GameVersionList = GameVersionList.OrderBy(g=>g.Name, GameNameComparer.Comparer).ToList();
```